# Advanced text editor control for .NET Windows apps

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, controls

I'm looking for a control that will help me to create `HTML` code for inserted text.

It should be something like extended `RichTextBox`, where I can:

- write some text inside,
- format my text using basic functions (fonts, sizes, colors, etc.),
- link images,
- **export my text as `HTML`**.

It could be `WPF` control as well.

Good example is StackOverflow's post editor:
[image: sample]

Answer (score 2):

You are asking for a WYSIWYG text input.

This normally works by a javascript class, which overrides a multiline textbox.

When the input is submitted to the server, it is then supplied as HTML.

This is one I have used in the past.
http://www.tinymce.com/

There are loads, as this is a common requirement.
If you want others, search google for "WYSIWYG editors".

Hope that helps.